# How can I download the source of this web url?

Tags: javascript, selenium, curl, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm trying to download the source of https://outline.com/rUdmgC. (I want to get the same file I get when I save that url using Chrome.)

I first tried wget and curl, which didn't work. (By didn't work, I mean the downloaded source was mostly empty; The page probably uses Javascript to create its content.)

Then I did some googling, and tried this https://gist.github.com/giocomai/247d54e097b5083e2451. It didn't work, and exited with these exceptions:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'suffix.startsWith('http:')')

  https://outline.com/app.js:20767
  https://outline.com/app.js:17217
  https://outline.com/app.js:17113 in onEachEvent
  https://outline.com/app.js:17210 in value
  https://outline.com/app.js:18695
  https://outline.com/app.js:18792
  https://outline.com/app.js:19000 in each
  https://outline.com/app.js:18792 in toggle
  https://outline.com/app.js:18683
  https://outline.com/app.js:19498 in mountTo
  https://outline.com/app.js:19638 in pushTags
  https://outline.com/app.js:19000 in each
  https://outline.com/app.js:19642 in pushTags
  https://outline.com/app.js:19693 in mount
  https://outline.com/app.js:20112
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" lang="en" class=" js csstransforms3d csstransitions" style=""><head>
        <title>Outline - Read &amp; annotate without distractions</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no,height=device-height">
        <meta name="description" content="Outline is a free service for reading and annotating news articles. We remove the clutter so you can analyze and comment on the content.">
        <meta name="keywords" content="clean links readable readability medium typography annotations annotate">

        <link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/daoolpmoieinofbnddaofhkhmbagfmnj">



        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://outline.com/css/outline.css?v=1.0.1">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://outline.com/favicon.png">

        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script src="https://outline.com/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://outline.com/app.js"></script>

        <script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
        <script>
          (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
            google_ad_client: "ca-pub-2748618594698147",
            enable_page_level_ads: true
          });
        </script>
    <style type="text/css">.yue { max-width: 650px; margin: 0 auto; }</style></head>
    <body>
        <outline-app></outline-app>
        <script>
            var riot = require('riot')
            require('initialize')
        </script>


</body></html>
```

What can I do?

Comment: *which didn't work* is not an error description. Which error message you get?

Comment: @jens No errors, but the page uses Javascript to create its content.

Comment: *TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'suffix.startsWith('http:')')* shows that this code only works for `http`not for `https`

Comment: @Jens I don't think that's the problem (I tried with http http://outline.com/rUdmgC too, and also it worked for https google.com), but even if it is, my question is about downloading that page, and that code is there only as an example of one of my failed attempts. Chill out.

Answer (score -1):

Oh yes, it does. To see the resulting page you should open the page in browser and see it in the developer mode.